# API works on Nodejs but returns empty array on react (client side)

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, node.js

I'm creating one application that process MySQL query and produce the output then I call the API on frontend using axios. Everything works fine on server side but when I try to call it on frontend it returns empty array only. Please guide me.

Nodejs Query:

```js
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  let sql =
    `select *from new_schema.images where username = ` +
    mysql.escape(req.signedCookies.name);
  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

Nodejs Output:

[image]

Everything works fine but only on server side. I have tried same method without the query (`mysql.escape(req.signedCookies.name)`) by hard-coding, then it works fine. Please help me.

Even in postman it returns empty array but it runs fine on browser:

[image]

It returns the exact same output on client side as well.

My full code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const router = express.Router();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
app.use(cors());

const dbs = require('./models');

dbs.sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
  console.log('Drop and re-sync db.');
});

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  connectionLimit: 10,
  database: '',
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('MYSQL Connected');
});
/**
 * Configure the middleware.
 * bodyParser.json() returns a function that is passed as a param to app.use() as middleware
 * With the help of this method, we can now send JSON to our express application.
 */
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// We export the router so that the server.js file can pick it up
module.exports = router;

const profile = require('./routes/api/profile');

app.use('/api/profile', profile);

// Combine react and node js servers while deploying( YOU MIGHT HAVE ALREADY DONE THIS BEFORE
// What you need to do is make the build directory on the heroku, which will contain the index.html of your react app and then point the HTTP request to the client/build directory
require('./db')();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set a static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  );
}
const auth = basicAuth({
  users: {
    admin: '123',
    user: '456',
  },
});

const s3 = new aws.S3({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_KEY,
  Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
});

app.use(cookieParser('82e4e438a0705fabf61f9854e3b575af'));

app.get('/authenticate', auth, (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    httpOnly: true,
    signed: true,
  };

  if (req.auth.user === 'admin') {
    res.cookie('name', 'admin', options).send({ screen: 'admin' });
  } else if (req.auth.user === 'user') {
    res.cookie('name', 'user', options).send({ screen: 'user' });
  }
});
app.get('/read-cookie', (req, res) => {
  if (req.signedCookies.name === 'admin') {
    res.send({ screen: 'admin' });
  } else if (req.signedCookies.name === 'user') {
    res.send({ screen: 'user' });
  } else {
    res.send({ screen: 'auth' });
  }
});

app.get('/clear-cookie', (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('name').end();
});

app.get('/db', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'select distinct dataset from new_schema.images';
  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  let sql =
    `select *from new_schema.images where username = ` +
    mysql.escape(req.signedCookies.name);
  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});

app.get('/pdata', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'select *from new_schema.images';
  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
app.get('/tables', (req, res) => {
  let sql = 'show tables';
  db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Cookies that have not been signed

  // Cookies that have been signed
  console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.signedCookies.name);
});

// Set up a port
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`));
```

Comment: How are you consuming your result on the client side? Btw `db.query(sql, (err, results) => ...` does not return a promise. So there is no point `await`ing it ...

Comment: show the client side call

Comment: And please show the exact query, which you are sending to the sql server. If you say, it works with hardcoded values but not with parameters, there might be an error in the query (and you don't seem to have any error handling that sends back an error to the client)

Comment: @derpirscher it works with param also but the thing is when i try to get using postman or client side it returns empty array whereas while i entered localhost:5000/files on browser it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure, postman is sending back any cookies to the server? Does your clientside correclty send the cookies? Can you check the request on the server if it, indeed, contains the cookies (and that they have the correct value)? Seems, the sqlquery is returing an empty result set ...

Comment: @derpirscher i parse the data through cookie parser so if i use ignito mode then it didn't work also. please guide me i want to pass the username in to that query

Comment: well, you may have a cookie-parser. But the cookie-parser middleware can only parse something, when it's part of the request. On the serverside, before sending the query to the sqlserver check if `req.signedCookies.name` does indeed have the correct value ... If not, the error is on the client side. But as you don't show what you are doing there, nobody can help you there ...

Comment: @derpirscher kindly check now i updated full code

Comment: Still that's only the SERVER side. For the request to work the cookie has to be sent by the CLIENT side. add a `console.log(req.signedCookies.name)` or `console.log(sql)` to your code. Then do the request and check if the correct username is logged at the server side. If not, the client is not sending a (valid) cookie ...

Comment: @derpirscher bro answer this question bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69666542/connect-2-dropdown-button-with-node-js-mysql-with-react